# Getting "Cannot multiply AFFINE and CONVEX" in cvxpy 0.4.10 but not 1.0.18

Tags: cvxpy

I'm working on two different environments which have different versions of cvxpy.

On **1.0.18**, this works as expected:

```
import cvxpy as cp

print(cp.__version__)

X = cp.Parameter(name='X', shape=(10), nonneg=True)
Y = cp.Variable(shape=(10))

print(X.T @ cp.abs(Y))

>>> Expression(CONVEX, NONNEGATIVE, ())
```

But on **0.4.10**, this does not:

```
import cvxpy as cp

print(cp.__version__)

X = cp.NonNegative(name='X', rows=10)
Y = cp.Variable(rows=10)

print(X.T @ cp.abs(Y))

>>> DCPError: Cannot multiply AFFINE and CONVEX.
```

Anyone know why? Did I do something wrong?

Much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`cp.NonNegative` is used to create a `Variable`, not a `Parameter`.

This works.

```
import cvxpy as cp

print(cp.__version__)

X = cp.Parameter(name='X', rows=10, sign='positive')
Y = cp.Variable(rows=10)

print(X.T @ cp.abs(Y))
```